# How to redirect user to the developer playstore page to see his other apps

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to redirect user to a given developer page on the Play store, to show the user what other apps the developer has.

What would be the link for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can make intent. This is basic hope that help

```
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                        i.setData(Uri.parse(ApplicationConstant.APP_PLAYSTORE_URL));
                                        startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code

Replace "com.example.android" with application package name which you want to open

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.example.android"));
 startActivity(intent);
```